# Grub on RAID1 - no such cyptodisk found

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, raid

My friend has a motherboard with a dual NVMe SSD slot configured in software RAID1 using mdadm.

We have installed Ubuntu Studio successfully in the past.

### Working past configuration:

#### lsblk

```
NAME                                    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
nvme0n1                                 259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
└─nvme0n1p1                             259:2    0 931.5G  0 part  
  └─md127                                 9:127  0 931.5G  0 raid1 
    ├─md127p1                           259:4    0   500M  0 part  /boot/efi
    ├─md127p2                           259:5    0     1G  0 part  /boot
    └─md127p3                           259:6    0   930G  0 part  
      └─ROOTFS                          253:1    0   930G  0 crypt 
        └─VG_SSD_ENCRYPTED-UbuntuStudio 253:2    0   930G  0 lvm   /
nvme1n1                                 259:1    0 931.5G  0 disk  
└─nvme1n1p1                             259:3    0 931.5G  0 part  
  └─md127                                 9:127  0 931.5G  0 raid1 
    ├─md127p1                           259:4    0   500M  0 part  /boot/efi
    ├─md127p2                           259:5    0     1G  0 part  /boot
    └─md127p3                           259:6    0   930G  0 part  
      └─ROOTFS                          253:1    0   930G  0 crypt 
        └─VG_SSD_ENCRYPTED-UbuntuStudio 253:2    0   930G  0 lvm   /
```

#### fstab

```
#<file system>  <mount point>     <type>    <options> <dump>    <pass>

# Ubuntu Studio ROOTFS
/dev/mapper/VG_SSD_ENCRYPTED-UbuntuStudio / ext4 defaults 0 0

# BOOT
UUID=8c332457-5df5-48bf-bfd9-ea2e8c0e77bf /boot ext4 defaults 0 0

# EFI
UUID=A38C-7AA5  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
```

#### mount

```
/dev/mapper/VG_SSD_ENCRYPTED-UbuntuStudio on / type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/md127p2 on /boot type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/md127p1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
```

#### crypttab

```
# <target name> <source device>         <key file>      <options>
md127p3_decrypted UUID=16de9a91-523f-4542-a8e7-2b7a2ea057d9 none luks
```

#### blkid

```
/dev/mapper/ROOTFS: UUID="iyQ9q9-OSKF-mjYO-jV37-2FDW-1XwQ-hZqNUt" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="36e82194-8a9e-675a-ff6d-4634df91a171" UUID_SUB="fbd1ef5b-c74b-3265-a20e-c8552af7fa26" LABEL="ubuntu-studio:RAID_SSD" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTLABEL="Linux RAID" PARTUUID="559b3506-b9c2-4e0b-a16f-706190670d04"
/dev/md127p3: UUID="16de9a91-523f-4542-a8e7-2b7a2ea057d9" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTLABEL="Linux LUKS" PARTUUID="08ca2107-d019-4378-9943-5e75b8b8022a"
/dev/md127p1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL_FATBOOT="ESP" LABEL="ESP" UUID="A38C-7AA5" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="44012383-3794-4e23-bb27-840d23cafc70"
/dev/md127p2: LABEL="BOOT" UUID="8c332457-5df5-48bf-bfd9-ea2e8c0e77bf" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Linux filesystem" PARTUUID="126ff1e6-7083-4c6c-a224-28e961509336"
/dev/mapper/VG_SSD_ENCRYPTED-UbuntuStudio: LABEL="UbuntuStudio" UUID="fbb51a49-f185-4144-a666-1cf53e4d73d8" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/nvme1n1p1: UUID="36e82194-8a9e-675a-ff6d-4634df91a171" UUID_SUB="e28ee1d1-6c4b-0480-44c4-de68f90fdae7" LABEL="ubuntu-studio:RAID_SSD" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTLABEL="Linux RAID" PARTUUID="0d232d4c-08f7-4da2-808a-beba317728ff"
```

#### Add UEFI nvram entry

```
sudo efibootmgr -c -d /dev/md127p1 -L 'Grub (perso)' -l '\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64-perso.efi'
```

#### efibootmgr -v

```
BootOrder: 0000,0001,0002,0003
Boot0000* Grub (perso)  HD(1,GPT,44012383-3794-4e23-bb27-840d23cafc70,0x800,0xfa000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64-perso.efi)
Boot0001* rEFInd        HD(1,GPT,44012383-3794-4e23-bb27-840d23cafc70,0x800,0xfa000)/File(\EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi)
Boot0002* Grub  HD(1,GPT,44012383-3794-4e23-bb27-840d23cafc70,0x800,0xfa000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi)
```

#### Generate a personnalized Grub EFI image :

```
sudo grub-mkimage -o /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64-perso.efi --format=x86_64-efi --prefix="(md/RAID_SSD,gpt1)/EFI/ubuntu" mdraid1x luks lvm cryptodisk linux ls cat normal part_gpt fat ext2 reboot gptsync part_gpt part_msdos configfile linuxefi gzio xzio lzopio search search_label search_fs_uuid search_fs_uuid search_fs_file all_video usb usb_keyboard test
```

### Current problem:

After attempting to upgrade to the newer system version, Grub was updating `grub.cfg` file, but now this config is broken.

It seems to have 2 problems:

1. `update-grub` : doesn't generate a correct `grub.cfg` file
2. Gurb efi image (personalized by grub-mkimage): no such cryptodisk found

Grub EFI payload: `ls` :

[image: Grub EFI payload: ls]

Grub EFI payload: `ls (md/RAID_SSD,gpt2)/` :

[image: Grub EFI payload: ls (md/RAID_SSD,gpt2)/]

Grub EFI payload: `no such cyptodisk found` :

[image: Grub EFI payload: no such cyptodisk found]

#### Grub efi payload info

```
$ du -h grubx64*
2,5M    grubx64.efi
832K    grubx64-perso.efi

$ file grubx64*
grubx64.efi:       PE32+ executable (EFI application) x86-64 (stripped to external PDB), for MS Windows, 5 sections
grubx64-perso.efi: PE32+ executable (EFI application) x86-64 (stripped to external PDB), for MS Windows, 4 sections
```

The size of `grubx64-perso.efi` seems to be small compared to the default.